# TYPO3 How insert tag <script> in RTE

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I use Typo3 7 and I try use the following code, the tag iframe and embed works fine, but tag script when processed in FE appear look like: "&lt ;script" instead < script>.

```
RTE.default {

      proc {
            allowTags := addToList(iframe,embed,script)

            allowTagsOutside := addToList(iframe,embed,script)

            entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in Page TSConfig the line:

```
RTE.default.removeTagsAndContents := removeFromList(iframe,embed,script)
```